# How to perform n time or query using ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

I have an array of values

```
values['value1','value2'....n]
```

I want to perform the following query

```
res = TheModel.objects.filter(key=values[0] or key = values[1] or key = values[2]...n)
```

Here the problem is array size may be different every time.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) filter:

```
res = TheModel.objects.filter(key__in=values)
```